# OpenOffice Calc sum of number less then a value

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I have a range of values F1:F144 and i want to make sum of values less than 50.

I tried `=SUM(F1:F144,'<'50)` but it doesn't work (i don't want to sort them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `=SUMIF(F1:F144;"<50")`

Comment: I had Err: 501 using this rule

Comment: i just replace , with ; and it work's ```=SUMIF(F1:F144;"<50")``` thank's

Comment: @cojody: It's best to always use `;` on this site, as that will work for any region in any version of LO or AOO. Commas only work with certain settings. However commas do work in MS Excel, in cases where the question asks about compatibility with that suite.

Comment: @Bouraoui Al-Moez L.A: Please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).